# How to avoid writing duplicate code

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Okay, I just have a question.

I need some expert advise; I have code, which is used by multiple clients. So that a good thing, no rewriting logic from the different clients, however the request and response objects across the different clients are difference; which is not a good thing., causing me to rewrite some logic.

Is there a way that I could alleviate from this? How could I cater for the different clients/services?

Comment: This *might* be an interesting question, but as it stands now, it is completely unclear and cannot be answered.

Comment: My first instinct is to tell you to use generics for the request and response objects (`public TResponse Process<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request)`). But we need a little more to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your shared code in a base class and put all specific code in an inheriting class.

```
public class MySharedCode
{
    public void MyShareMethodA()
    {
        // Shared code.
    }

    public void MyShareMethodB()
    {
        // Shared code.
    }
}

public class SpecificCodeForASpecificClient:MySharedCode
{
    public void SendRequest(MySpecificRequestA request)
    {
        // Specific code.
    }

    public MySpecificResponse ReadRepsonse()
    {
        // Specific code.
    }
}
```

Is this what your are looking for? Or is the send/receive code the same voor all clients? In that case you could try generics:

```
public class MySharedCode<TRequest, TResponse>
    where: TResponse: new()
{
    public void MyShareMethodA()
    {
        // Shared code.
    }

    public void MyShareMethodB()
    {
        // Shared code.
    }

    public void SendRequest(TRequest request)
    {
        // Shared code with specific request.
    }

    public TResponse ReadRepsonse()
    {
        // Shared code with specific response.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Wrap what is different in classes with the same interface

Step 2. make the common logic work with wrapper class